# CSS: Why are my tooltips getting positioned incorrectly?

Tags: css, tooltip, css-grid

On my website, I have a grid with skills rated from 1-5 with stars. When you hover over a row, you'll get a tooltip interpreting the star rating:

[image]

The issue is that on smaller screens, some of the skill names wrap multiple lines, and that causes the tooltip to jump up quite a bit:

[image]

Below is a minimal re-created version of the source, without all the fluff. The only selectors of note are `tooltip` and `tooltip-text`. Basically, I inspected [W3 Schools's tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) to learn how to create my own.

**How it works**: You add the `tooltip` wrapper, with its nested `tooltip-text`, inside whatever element is going to get hovered. That parent element needs to have a position set to `relative`. This allows the `tooltip` wrapper to be positioned absolutely, with 100% width and height, so that hovering the parent is essentially equivalent to hovering the tooltip. Then, you can position the text relative to the `tooltip` wrapper.

**But what is causing the tooltips to be misaligned on smaller screens?**

**NOTE**: Please excuse the ill-formatted HTML. I ran over the character limit and had to improvise. Full stars are represented with `f` and empty with `e` to save space.

```css
.tooltip {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top {
  bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right {
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  right: 100%;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  display: flex;
}
#skills #skill-grid {
  column-gap: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  row-gap: 40px;
}
#skills .skill-category {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#skills .skill-item {
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#skills .skill-item .tooltip-text {
  max-width: 100px;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-name {
  grid-column: 1;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating {
  align-self: center;
  display: inline;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: right;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating .star {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.star {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="container section">
<h2 class="heading-with-image">
<span>Skills and Abilities</span>
</h2>
<div id="skill-grid">
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Programming Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C++</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Python</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">TypeScript (ES6)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Kotlin</span>
<div class="skill-rating">ffffe</div>                
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C# (Unity)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Frontend &amp; Backend</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">HTML5</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">CSS/SASS/LESS</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">React (+Ant Design)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">SQL (Oracle, postgres)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">NodeJS, Express</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Software Development</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">OOP</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Debugging</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Code review</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Scrum</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Refactoring</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Game dev</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Design patterns</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Operating Systems</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Windows (7-10)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux (Ubuntu)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux kernel</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VMs (VirtualBox)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">macOS (Mojave)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">IDEs and Editors</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VS Code</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Visual Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Qt Creator</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Android Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Collaboration</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Git, GitHub</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Slack</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">G Suite</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Jira</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Confluence</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">English</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Armenian</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">German</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Other</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy editing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Technical writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, I suggest you use https://jsfiddle.net/ for neatness - Also, can you add a media query for mobile as in = .tooltip .tooltip-top {
  bottom: calc(50% + 10px); /* Instead of 100% to see if it works on 2 liners skills */
} Your tooltips are might be using your parents height and since you position them on a percent(%) basis, things can get weird.

Comment: You can simulate mobile by clicking Run Code Snippet > Full Page and then opening up your dev tools and resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Approach 1

*following the OP's code without any changes*

#### Issue

The issue is that position absolute and bottom are on different elements and so css bottom is giving the results differently from expectations.

#### Fix

`tooltip-top` needs to be **position: absolute** because you are calculating the bottom for that one

#### Explanation

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom):

- When position is set to absolute or fixed, the bottom property specifies the distance between the element's bottom edge and the bottom edge of its containing block. **(This is what needs to be done)**
- When position is set to relative, the bottom property specifies the distance the element's bottom edge is moved above its normal position. **(This is currently happening. Since position is missing, it behaves as relative and thus its bottom is moved above from its normal position. So, for more height parents, it moves more)**

bottom is parent height + 10px so for parents occupying 2 lines, height is more and it is moved more than 1 line parents. When position is absolute, even though height for elements occupying 2 lines is more, bottom is calculated from bottom of that parent and so height indirectly nullified and it behaves as per expectation.

#### Code

```
.tooltip-text .tooltip-top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
}
```

#### Modified Code Snippet

```css
.tooltip {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top {
  bottom: calc(50% + 10px);
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right {
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  right: 100%;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  display: flex;
}
#skills #skill-grid {
  column-gap: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  row-gap: 40px;
}
#skills .skill-category {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#skills .skill-item {
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#skills .skill-item .tooltip-text {
  max-width: 100px;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-name {
  grid-column: 1;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating {
  align-self: center;
  display: inline;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: right;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating .star {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.star {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="container section">
<h2 class="heading-with-image">
<span>Skills and Abilities</span>
</h2>
<div id="skill-grid">
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Programming Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C++</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Python</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">TypeScript (ES6)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Kotlin</span>
<div class="skill-rating">ffffe</div>                
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C# (Unity)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Frontend &amp; Backend</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">HTML5</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">CSS/SASS/LESS</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">React (+Ant Design)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">SQL (Oracle, postgres)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">NodeJS, Express</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Software Development</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">OOP</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Debugging</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Code review</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Scrum</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Refactoring</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Game dev</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Design patterns</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Operating Systems</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Windows (7-10)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux (Ubuntu)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux kernel</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VMs (VirtualBox)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">macOS (Mojave)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">IDEs and Editors</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VS Code</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Visual Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Qt Creator</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Android Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Collaboration</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Git, GitHub</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Slack</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">G Suite</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Jira</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Confluence</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">English</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Armenian</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">German</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Other</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy editing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Technical writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

---

## Approach 2

*Modified OP's code and simplified it*

#### Issues

- HTML structure is not proper (can be improved).
- Lot of `position: absolute` at many places for tooltip positioning which is problematic
- `Lot of calculations in css` (left, width, min-width etc) which are not required

#### Fixes

- Have simplified the HTML along with classes and css
- Using `position: absolute` at one place for tooltip positioning
- Removed left, width and other unnecessary css
- .tooltip is now child of .skill-rating which is much required for proper working

You can switch `position: relative; css between .skill-item and .skill-rating for the position of the tool tip`.

- If you want tooltip with respect to rating, apply `position: relative;` to .skill-rating
- If you want tooltip with respect to full div (rating + name), apply `position: relative;` .skill-item

#### Modified Code Snippet

```css
.skill-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.skill-rating {

}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.tooltip-text {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.skill-item:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 class="skill-category">Programming Languages</h3>
  <div class="skill-item">
    <div class="skill-name">
      C++
    </div>
    <div class="skill-rating">
      fffff
      <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="tooltip-text">
          Advanced
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-item">
    <div class="skill-name">Python</div>
    <div class="skill-rating">
      fffff
      <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="tooltip-text">
          Intermediate
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-item">
    <div class="skill-name">TypeScript Language (Ecma Script 6)</div>
    <div class="skill-rating">
      fffff
      <div class="tooltip">
        <div class="tooltip-text">
          Advanced
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Have added another approach for the problem

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: The reason I haven't accepted/awarded this yet is because it doesn't actually work as intended. If the font size remains 18px, everything is fine. As soon as you reduce the font size for the tooltips, you'll notice that they no longer align with the far right of their parent container as I had tried to get them to, and they actually end up somewhere in the middle of their parent instead of 10px above. For some reason, if I set position to absolute on the tooltip text, I'm unable to enforce any width constraints on them.

Comment: @AleksandrH The position is governed by `left: calc(100% - 100px)` css for `#skills .skill-item .tooltip-text` and that can be played upon to get the value. If I apply `font-size: 10px` and `left: calc(100% - 50px)` to the same, it seems to work. I am assuming that tooltip font-size is fixed here.

Comment: @AleksandrH Have added another approach to your problem simplifying html and css. This will solve the problems you have mentioned above

Comment: Sounds good! I'll take a look in a bit and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Your second approach worked. Note that the HTML was ill-formatted only in my post to save space; it's fine on the site. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**As it depends on screen size,check in full screen size & try to change the screen size**

> it may not showed exactly positioned,but i was set the hint.It shows perfect in my screen.So,you need to check and change the media query rules to fit all the screen.

You may edit media query css rules to ensure tooltip positioned pixel perfect. However, where i edit your css file mention with some block comment **`/*this was added*/`** and **`/*this was changed*/`** marked.

```css
.tooltip {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  
  /*this was changed*/
    /*font-size: 1.4rem;*/
  /*this was changed*/
  
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top {
/*    margin-top: -13%; */
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right {
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  right: 100%;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}
/*this was added*/

.skill-item:hover{
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#e3e3e3;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/*this was added*/
/*this was changed*/

.skill-item:hover .tooltip > .tooltip-text {
  display: flex;
}

/*this was changed*/
#skills #skill-grid {
  column-gap: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  row-gap: 40px;
}
#skills .skill-category {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#skills .skill-item {
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  
  /*this was added*/
  
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  
  /*this was added*/
}
#skills .skill-item .tooltip-text {
  max-width: 100px;
  /*this was changed*/
  
  /*for centered alignment*/
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  
  /*this was changed*/
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-name {
  grid-column: 1;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating {
  align-self: center;
  display: inline;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: right;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating .star {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.star {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}
/*this was added*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .tooltip .tooltip-top {
    margin-top: -6%;
 background:green;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .tooltip .tooltip-top {
    margin-top: -6%;
 background:blue;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 660px) {
  .tooltip .tooltip-top {
    margin-top: -11%;
 background:black;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .tooltip .tooltip-top {
    margin-top: -9%;
 background:red;
  }
}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .tooltip .tooltip-top {
    margin-top: -11%;
 background:yellow;
  }
}
/*this was added*/
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="container section">
<h2 class="heading-with-image">
<span>Skills and Abilities</span>
</h2>
<div id="skill-grid">
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Programming Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C++</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Python</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">TypeScript (ES6)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Kotlin</span>
<div class="skill-rating">ffffe</div>                
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C# (Unity)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Frontend &amp; Backend</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">HTML5</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">CSS/SASS/LESS</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">React (+Ant Design)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">SQL (Oracle, postgres)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">NodeJS, Express</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Software Development</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">OOP</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Debugging</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Code review</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Scrum</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Refactoring</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Game dev</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Design patterns</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Operating Systems</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Windows (7-10)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux (Ubuntu)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux kernel</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VMs (VirtualBox)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">macOS (Mojave)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">IDEs and Editors</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VS Code</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Visual Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Qt Creator</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Android Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Collaboration</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Git, GitHub</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Slack</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">G Suite</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Jira</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Confluence</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">English</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Armenian</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">German</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Other</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy editing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Technical writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense and is a bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score -1):

**Issue- what is causing the tooltips to be misaligned on smaller screens?**

**Reason**: 
By default, the width and height of an element is calculated like this:

width + padding + border = actual width of an element

height + padding + border = actual height of an element

This means: When you set the width/height of an element, the element often appears bigger than you have set (because the element's border and padding are added to the element's specified width/height).

**Solution**: The **box-sizing** property solves this problem (I have assigned it to **.tooltip .tooltip-text** class).

*Note that after assigning box-sizing property overflow problem solved but tooltip look is compromised, to solve this issue you have to design it in such a way that will support all screen sizes (That's the Responsiveness design).*

You can learn more about "box-sizing" [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp).

```css
.tooltip {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDED PROPERTY */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top {
  bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-top::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right {
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-right::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.tooltip .tooltip-bottom::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  right: 100%;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-left::after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
  display: flex;
}
#skills #skill-grid {
  column-gap: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  row-gap: 40px;
}
#skills .skill-category {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#skills .skill-item {
  column-gap: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#skills .skill-item .tooltip-text {
  max-width: 100px;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-name {
  grid-column: 1;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating {
  align-self: center;
  display: inline;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: right;
}
#skills .skill-item .skill-rating .star {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.star {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="container section">
<h2 class="heading-with-image">
<span>Skills and Abilities</span>
</h2>
<div id="skill-grid">
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Programming Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C++</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Python</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">TypeScript (ES6)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Kotlin</span>
<div class="skill-rating">ffffe</div>                
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">C# (Unity)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Frontend &amp; Backend</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">HTML5</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">CSS/SASS/LESS</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">React (+Ant Design)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">SQL (Oracle, postgres)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">NodeJS, Express</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Software Development</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">OOP</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Debugging</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Code review</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Scrum</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Refactoring</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Game dev</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Design patterns</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Operating Systems</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Windows (7-10)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux (Ubuntu)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Linux kernel</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VMs (VirtualBox)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">macOS (Mojave)</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">IDEs and Editors</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">VS Code</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Visual Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Qt Creator</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Android Studio</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Collaboration</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Git, GitHub</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Slack</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">G Suite</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Jira</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Confluence</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Languages</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">English</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Armenian</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">German</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffee
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Intermediate
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="skill-category">Other</h3>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy editing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Technical writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
fffff
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Advanced
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="skill-item">
<span class="skill-name">Copy writing</span>
<div class="skill-rating">
ffffe
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
<div class="tooltip-text tooltip-top">
Competent
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I already have box-sizing on my site, set in a global stylesheet.

Comment: Its not about having box-sizing property for the whole website, its about for the specific element on which you want to have an actual size(in your case its .tooltip-text).

Comment: Yes, but every element on my site is given the box-sizing property via the wildcard selector: `* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: You can see in chrome debugger its not getting set the box-sizing property for .tooltip-text by your wildcard selector, may be its getting over written from some where else. BTW setting the box-sizing property for .tooltip-text its working and that is the easiest solution. The accepted answer has lot of editing. I recommend look my answer again and the rest is on you. Thats all I can say, Thanks.